# Swift: position an SKshapeNode to the far left/right but not offscreen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sknode

Im trying to get two SKshapeNodes to be positioned on the far left and far right of the screen without any part of the nodes offscreen like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rhAH.png. I don't want one node to be positioned according to the other node though.
Ive been trying to use minX and maxX and use the width of the screen and SKshapeNodes and I can't figure it out.

This is what I have so far

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let firstShapeNode = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        firstShapeNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height / 2)
        firstShapeNode.fillColor = SKColor.purpleColor()
        self.addChild(firstShapeNode)

        let secondShapeNode = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        secondShapeNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height / 2)
        secondShapeNode.fillColor = SKColor.cyanColor()
        self.addChild(secondShapeNode)

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: use the frame property

Comment: i am using the frame property

Comment: If you post the code you are using to layout the nodes, it will help get to a solution more swiftly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align the nodes to the left and right sides of the screen, respectively, try this:

```
firstShapeNode.position = CGPoint(x: firstShapeNode.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
secondShapeNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX - secondShapeNode.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
```

In SpriteKit, unlike UIKit, the default origin (0,0) point on the screen is in the bottom left corner. Additionally, by default, the `position` of an `SKNode` is the center of the node, which is why they need to be offset by half of their width.

Comment: why would this not work for SKShapeNodes, , the only thing wrong is it should be `firstShapeNode.frame.size.width`  and I have no idea why nathan is using `self.view` should be the scene frame, not the view frame

Comment: @Swift What kind of issues are you facing when you try to use this? (Also fixed my answer to use the scene's frame.)

Comment: @nathan  size is not a property of SKNode, it is a property of SKSpriteNode